# Implementing Coffeescript into Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript that I am trying to add into my current rails application. Once the script is in the assets/javascript folder how do I actually make it display on the page? I've gone through a bunch of tutorials and am still completely lost. Do I need to make a new controller?

Comment: It would help if you posted your coffeescript and gave us some indication of what it was supposed to do. Your script could be anything, so "make it display" becomes a pretty vague request. And no, you don't need a new controller.

Answer (score 2):

Coffeescript is included as a default gem in Rails. Confirm by checking in your Gemfile.

Coffeescript is a language that compiles, so it won't 'display' on a page -- when you make a `.coffee` file, Rails will compile it to JavaScript when the page is loaded (or before, depending on how you do asset compilation). A coffeescript page is included the same way a js page is included (open your `application.js` page -- it'll have a comment explaining how to include JS).